# How to draw a perfect square using tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

```
I want to create a square on mouse drag. I can only create rectangles with
```

`canvas.create_rectangle(oldX,oldY , newX , newY,fill = 'red',outline = "")`

Is there any method to create square only?

Comment: A square is just a rectangle with equal length sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the maximum or minimum of the width and height to be the size of the square:

```
dx, dy = newX-oldX, newY-oldY
signx = 1 if dx >= 0 else -1
signy = 1 if dy >= 0 else -1
# user either min() or max() in below statement
size = max(abs(dx), abs(dy))
canvas.create_rectangle(oldX, oldY, oldX+size*signx, oldY+size*signy, fill='red', outline='', tag='rect')
```